# Why does adding salt to the water keep your eggs from exploding?

Tags: food-science

Why does adding salt to the water you boil your eggs in keeping them from bursting? Interested in the science behind this piece of culinary science

Comment: I don't think it does. It would be helpful if you would cite the source of this information in your question.

Comment: I cook eggs in unsalted water and they *don't* explode, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the theory is that it keeps them from cracking or exploding, rather, *if* they crack, the white will solidify more readily in salted water, keeping the mess to a minimum. That quick congealing of the white potentially seals the "leak" minimizing further mess.

Comment: I had heard this about vinegar but not salt; I'd be interested to hear whether salting water would actually have this effect (although I agree that this is the likely intended reason for adding salt).

Comment: There's also that the water will be hotter with salt, which might just seal the cracks faster.

Comment: That would also be a myth, though, since salted water only boils a degree or so hotter.